# How can I define my own date format in PHP?

Tags: php, date, calendar

Could you clarify me, how can I define my own date format in PHP ?

For instance, I have a date variable.

And I want to output this date as a date of the Ancient Roman calendar. Or in format of the French revolution calendar. These calendars, for example, begin not from the Christmas and have other names of months.

Also some calendars don't have weeks in 7 days, but have "weeks" in another quantity of days.

Or in format as "year and season". For example, "2016, the summer".

Is it possible to add a date format in PHP date formats and somehow code its output ?

Comment: If you can define it, you can code it. Each of your examples would require its own set of code

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime {
      public string format ( $format ) {
             if ($format == "RD") { 
                //Convert to roman date
                return $romanDateFormat;

             }
             return parent::format($format);
      }

}
```

Then only use `MyDateTime` instead of `DateTime`

You can't directly add new format for the built-in DateTime object to handle as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible just define your own function.
the way  I think most poeple would do this is by create a functions.php file where your store your function and other custom functions.
Then include functions.php in the file where you want to display roman date.
Then declare your function :

```
function translateToRomanCalendar($date = ""){//declare function

   $romanDate = "";//declare roman date variable

   //Put the translation code here. Using tests and stuff to store 
   //the  roman date  in the romanDate variable

   return $romanDate;//return the roman date

}
```

Then just call that function in your php file: for example to display the translated current year you would do

```
<?php echo translateToRomanCalendar(date('Y')) ?>
```

This will echo the return value of the function ($romanDate's value).

Now what will be tricky is the actual function's code; you have to test for date format and stuff.

anyways hope that helps there is tons of material on the web about php functions.

Regards

Alex

Comment: No, I meant the following.  Can I define, for example, date format "RD" and afterwards write this code ?
`<?php echo date('RD'); ?>`
And "RD" should have outputed as "Roman date" for the date variable.
Is it possible in PHP ?

Comment: No but `<php echo myDate('RD'); ?>` shouldn't really be a problem

Comment: Can someone tell me what is wrong with my answer? Why would we have to go through a class definition and not just a function?